lerna "Assuming all packages changed" for new branches
I have a monorepo with Lerna configured version to independent.
the problem is whenever create i a new git branch and run version or publish I get Assuming all packages changed  and lerna wants to bump all packages although I didn't do any change. if I go back to master lerna will know to continue from there.
I tried running it with --include-merged-tags but it didn't help as well
if I do publish from-package then it works well but that means I need to handle the version manually, something I want to avoid
